# How is whole body control different from computed torque control?

Tags: control, humanoid

From my understanding Whole body control is built upon Computed Torque control. What is the difference between the two? What is the way for whole body control if the dynamic model is not available?

Answer (score 1):

[Whole body control (WBC)](http://www.ieee-ras.org/whole-body-control) refers to how to control antropmorph structure (as a system), while the [computed torque control (CTC)](http://mars.uta.edu/me5337/reference/CTpidI.pdf) is a method to compute the torque in 1 single joint (i.e. to control 1 element in a system). Computed torque control can be used only is you have an (inverse) dynamic model. I cannot comment on the question of using WBC without a dynamic model, I am not aware of any possiblities to do so.